# Dozer Deep Mapping with Annotations

Tags: java, dozer

Unable to map deep mapping from Source class to Target class `SourceEmployee.Address.houseName` to `TargetEmployee.houseName`

Source object class

```
public class SourceEmployee 
{   
    private String empName;
    private Address addr;


    enter code here

    @Mapping("empName")
    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }
    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }   
    public Address getAddr() {
        return addr;
    }

    public void setAddr(Address addr) {
        this.addr = addr;
    }   
}
```

Address class

```
public class Address 
{
    private String houseName;
    public String getHouseName() {
        return houseName;
    }
    public void setHouseName(String houseName) {
        this.houseName = houseName;
    }
}
```

target object

```
public class TargetEmployee 
{

    private String empName;
    private String houseName;

    public String getHouseName() {
        return houseName;
    }
    public void setHouseName(String houseName) {
        this.houseName = houseName;
    }
    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }
    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }
}
```

Main class copying from source to destination

```
public class CopyAttributes 
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SourceEmployee sourceEmp = new SourceEmployee();
        sourceEmp.setEmpName("Rafi");

        Address adr = new Address();        
        adr.setHouseName("Aashiyana");
        sourceEmp.setAddr(adr);

        Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
        TargetEmployee destObject = mapper.map(sourceEmp, TargetEmployee.class);

        System.out.println(destObject.getEmpName());
        System.out.println(destObject.getHouseName());

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the Dependency for @Mapping annotation, I am using Camel-Dozer component

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else run into the same problem, I manage to correct that case by doing this :

```
public class TargetEmployee 
{

    private String empName;
    private String houseName;

    @Mapping("addr.houseName")
    public String getHouseName() {
        return houseName;
    }
    public void setHouseName(String houseName) {
        this.houseName = houseName;
    }
    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }
    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }
}
```

The

```
@Mapping("empName")
```

set in SourceEmployee Isn't necessary

Answer (score 3):

it's enough to add this annotation in the source class (SourceEmployee):

```
@Mapping("this")
private Address addr;
```

In fact, "this" means "remain on the same node"; after that, houseName will match between Address and TargetEmployee.

;)

Alex